# How to get specific Id of an item in the Listview from the index?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a list of item in itemview, which by pressing a button I can add new item to it. However, I am not sure how to retrieve the ID of the latest created item. What I have done is getting the size of the array and -1 to get the index number of the latest added item:

```
int lastItemIndex= listItems.size()-1;
```

Then I have used the idex number to the get the object back:

```
string lastitem= listItems.get(lastItemIndex);
```

However I don't know how to get the item's id ?

I can't think of any better way and I am really stuck. I am sure there is a much smarter way of doing it.

It is pretty simple to retrive the id of an item when the item is clicked, by using:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID)
{}
```

But does anyone know how to get the id without clicking on an item? Technically I want to use the same ID as the Key-ID to import it to the database.

Comment: I am using ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; :-)

Comment: then try `id=arrayofStrings[position]`

Comment: isn't there a getItemId(int position) on the adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as straightforward as :

```
listView.getAdapter().getItemId(position);
```

with position for the last item being :

```
int position = listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
```

Comment: Yep thats it, many thanks it worked. I am so idiot I have used int lastItemIndex= listItems.size()-1;
        
        long id=adapter.getItemId(lastItemIndex);

Comment: Does the id change if if I delete an item from the list? I mean if I delete item ID2, then item with the ID3 will turn to id 2? or the item  id will not change?

Comment: the actual id depends on the implementation of the adapter. An arrayAdapter uses the index as id, a cursorAdapter uses the _ID column of the cursor, custom adapters can define custom values ...

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how to use and add custom ids?

Comment: in your case (ArrayAdapter) you need to override getItemId, which by default returns position. You can, for instance, have it return getItem(position).hashCode()